# Deploying grails application to Oracle iPlanet Web Server

Tags: database, oracle, hibernate, grails, datasource

I have project that connects to a few Oracle 11g databases. So I have 3 different logins. This does fine when I run it locally from my grails ide. It was a doozy getting it started at first, but it works. Initially my issue had to do with the hibernate version. Currently it's 3.6.10.10. Now my problem is deploying it to the test server. The server used is Oracle iPlanet Web Server 7.0.15. I have the following in my datasource.groovy, and the error follows.

```
dataSource {
    dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
    pooled = true
    properties {
        maxActive = -1
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
        numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
        testOnBorrow=true
        testWhileIdle=true
        testOnReturn=true
        validationQuery="SELECT 1 from dual"
    }
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
    showsql = true
}

environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            url = "jdbc:oracle:oci:@database.whatever.com"
            username="data_user"
            password = "some_pw"
            driverClassName = 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'
        }
        dataSource_task {
            url = "jdbc:oracle:oci8:@someotherdatabase.whatever.com"
            username="other_user"
            password = "other_pw"
            driverClassName = 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'
        }
    }

}
```

This is not the whole stacktrace. I had to put what I thought was relevant due to the size limit here.

```
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout: 2014-12-02 14:52:24,569 [main] ERROR pool.ConnectionPool  - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.checkError(T2CConnection.java:689)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.logon(T2CConnection.java:401)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:531)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.<init>(T2CConnection.java:148)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CDriverExtension.getConnection(T2CDriverExtension.java:53)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:503)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:278)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:701)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:635)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:486)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:144)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:116)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:103)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:127)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.afterPropertiesSet(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:162)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.<init>(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:106)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:121)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:277)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1075)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:979)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:123)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:320)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:645)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:145)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1075)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:979)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:123)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:320)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1158)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:123)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:320)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1158)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:123)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.support.TransactionManagerPostProcessor.initialize(TransactionManagerPostProcessor.java:74)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.support.TransactionManagerPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(TransactionManagerPostProcessor.java:52)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1532)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1500)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:123)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:720)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.getApplicationContext(DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.java:156)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:169)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:127)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsConfigUtils.configureWebApplicationContext(GrailsConfigUtils.java:122)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:108)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4476)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5133)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at com.sun.webserver.connector.nsapi.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:240)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1224)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:924)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1224)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:520)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded.start(Embedded.java:917)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at com.sun.enterprise.web.PwcWebContainer.onStartup(PwcWebContainer.java:70)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at com.sun.webserver.connector.nsapi.WebContainer.start(WebContainer.java:497)
[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout:  at com.sun.webserver.init.J2EERunner.confPostInit(J2EERunner.java:304)




[02/Dec/2014:14:52:24] info  : stdout: 2014-12-02 14:52:24,632 [main] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This appears to be a database configuration question rather than a programming question.  Put another way, I don't think there's a bug in your code; I think this is entirely due to configuration differences between your test environment and your development environment.  As such you will probably get more targeted answers on ServerFault or dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Also, it appears to me that only the very first two and very last two lines of the stack trace contain any useful information.

Comment: @Zack Thanks. I didn't realize stackoverflow was a branch of stackexchange. Most of my research ends up in stackoverflow. I'll go to ServerFault. Like I said it does what it supposed to do locally, it just causes problems on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a colleague, I found out the issue was my start script for the program. It had to point to the jdk home on the server. It is now working.